# Can we get tabs like in Stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

I really like the [customizable tabs in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) where I really can filter for questions I'm interested in.

(When) Can we have it here?

## Update

I've asked this question almost a year ago, do we have any news on this topic?

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks? ;)

Comment: :D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D

Comment: When we get it will depend when our Stackexchange corporate overlords decide we can have it

Comment: Yup, and I am told they read the metas. FIngers crossed,